# HashMap get method returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, minecraft, bukkit

I have a problem in my plugin (Bukkit for Minecraft) that makes this function throw a NullPointerException on line 733 (I cut many parts, the lines are separated), on the .get() method of the HashMap class. It could also be the condition just before, I don't really know or understand what's going on. Before I checked for .containsKey(), it errored on the .get().

```
private float getTempFromArmor(Player player) {
    float armorValue = 0.0F;
    ItemStack helmet = player.getEquipment().getHelmet();
    ItemStack chestplate = player.getEquipment().getChestplate();
    ItemStack leggings = player.getEquipment().getLeggings();
    ItemStack boots = player.getEquipment().getBoots();
    HashMap<Material, Float> helmetValues = new HashMap<Material, Float>();
        helmetValues.put(Material.LEATHER_HELMET, 0.2F);
        helmetValues.put(Material.IRON_HELMET, -0.2F);
        helmetValues.put(Material.CHAINMAIL_HELMET, -0.1F);
        helmetValues.put(Material.GOLD_HELMET, 0.1F);
        helmetValues.put(Material.DIAMOND_HELMET, 0.0F);
    HashMap<Material, Float> chestplateValues = new HashMap<Material, Float>();
        chestplateValues.put(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE, 0.3F);
        chestplateValues.put(Material.IRON_CHESTPLATE, -0.3F);
        chestplateValues.put(Material.CHAINMAIL_CHESTPLATE, -0.15F);
        chestplateValues.put(Material.GOLD_CHESTPLATE, 0.15F);
        chestplateValues.put(Material.DIAMOND_CHESTPLATE, 0.0F);
    HashMap<Material, Float> leggingsValues = new HashMap<Material, Float>();
        leggingsValues.put(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS, 0.2F);
        leggingsValues.put(Material.IRON_LEGGINGS, -0.2F);
        leggingsValues.put(Material.CHAINMAIL_LEGGINGS, -0.1F);
        leggingsValues.put(Material.GOLD_LEGGINGS, 0.1F);
        leggingsValues.put(Material.DIAMOND_LEGGINGS, 0.0F);
    HashMap<Material, Float> bootsValues = new HashMap<Material, Float>();
        bootsValues.put(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS, 0.1F);
        bootsValues.put(Material.IRON_BOOTS, -0.1F);
        bootsValues.put(Material.CHAINMAIL_BOOTS, -0.05F);
        bootsValues.put(Material.GOLD_BOOTS, 0.05F);
        bootsValues.put(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS, 0.0F);
```

From here

```
        if (helmetValues.containsKey(helmet.getType()))
            armorValue += helmetValues.get(helmet.getType());
```

To here

```
        if (chestplateValues.containsKey(chestplate.getType()))
            armorValue += chestplateValues.get(chestplate.getType());
        if (leggingsValues.containsKey(leggings.getType()))
            armorValue += leggingsValues.get(leggings.getType());
        if (bootsValues.containsKey(boots.getType()))
            armorValue += bootsValues.get(boots.getType());
    if (armorValue > 0) armorValue *= armorMax;
    else armorValue *= armorMin;
    return MathHelper.clamp_float(armorValue, armorMin, armorMax);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
[07:21:55 WARN]: [Hardcore Biomes] Task #4 for Hardcore Biomes v0.6.2 generated an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at name.sml.franky1223.hardcorebiomes.HardcoreBiomes.getTempFromArmor(HardcoreBiomes.java:733) ~[?:?]
    at name.sml.franky1223.hardcorebiomes.HardcoreBiomes.access$10(HardcoreBiomes.java:703) ~[?:?]
    at name.sml.franky1223.hardcorebiomes.HardcoreBiomes$1.run(HardcoreBiomes.java:169) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:53) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:345) [craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:587) [craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.DedicatedServer.u(DedicatedServer.java:250) [craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:545) [craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:457) [craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:617) [craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.2.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
```

Please help me, I am very confused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `Material`? An `enum`, `class`? Please show it's definition.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us the exact line the NullPointerException is being thrown from (not just the line number which is not very useful in snippets of code). Can you reduce your code to a small example to better demonstrate and isolate the problem? Posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be best.

Comment: I already identified the two possible lines of code (732 and 733):

`if (helmetValues.containsKey(helmet.getType()))
armorValue += helmetValues.get(helmet.getType());`

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you need Minecraft with a Bukkit server to test my plugin, even if I shorten the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should not raise NullPointerException

```
    if ( helmet != null ) {
Float helmetArmor = helmetValues.get(helmet.getType();
if ( helmetArmor != null ) {
     armorValue += helmetArmor ;
}
```

}

Maybe your player has not helmet?

Comment: Thank you it worked! I forgot to check if the armor piece existed in the first place. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Providing all that code is in the same method, I suspect the problem is less likely to be coming from this part:

```
helmetValues.get();
```

and more likely to be coming from:

```
helmet.getType()
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```
if (helmet != null && helmetValues.containsKey(helmet.getType())) {
  armorValue += helmetValues.get(helmet.getType());
}
```